クラウド環境におけるスクレイピングでcloudflareが突破できない
概要
OCI環境でcloudflareを突破するスクレイピングの処理を実現したいのですがうまくいきません。
以下に示すように、複数の方法でローカルでは成功するのにクラウド環境で成功しないのですが、これはOCIのIPアドレスがcloudflareのブラックリストに載っていると理解した方が良いのでしょうか？
知見をお持ちの方いらっしゃいましたらご教授いただけますと幸いです。
試したこと
pythonでのスクレイピング

nodriver：モジュール
drissionpage：モジュール
flaresolverr：dockerのプロキシ

環境
ローカル

マシン：Mac mini M2チップ
macOS：Sonoma14.6.1

クラウド環境

OKE（oracle linux（arm基盤））
OCI instance（oracle linux（arm基盤）, Ubuntu）

成否
nodriver

ローカル：Mac上で実行しcloudflareを突破
クラウド環境：OCI instanse上で実行しcloudflareの突破失敗（処理自体は正常に終了）

drissionpage

ローカル：Mac上で実行しcloudflareを突破
クラウド環境：OCI instanse上で実行しcloudflareの突破失敗（処理自体は正常に終了）

flaresolverr

ローカル：Mac上でdocker composeを実行しプロキシコンテナを立てた上で、pythonからプロキシを通してcloudflareを突破
クラウド環境（OKE）：プロキシのPODを起動しpythonからプロキシを通してcloudflareの突破失敗（処理自体は正常に終了）
クラウド環境（OCI instanse）：instanse上でdocker composeを実行しプロキシコンテナを立てた上で、pythonからプロキシを通してcloudflareの突破失敗（処理自体は正常に終了）


マルチポスト先: https://qiita.com/yamamuratkr/questions/362a23cd8c8aaab03c87#answer-4c0d171eb087a29a1330
